# Select a specific area of selected cells to PDF then print using VBA in a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

i have this worksheet called Test. In that worksheet i want to export to pdf then print cells G1 to cells H17. Next i want to print G1 to cells I17 skipping column H meaning without column H. In another word column G is kind of like the header and the columns that follow the result. So print Header column+ results column and so on until column CM. Below each printing page i want to also export to pdf column C18, column D18 and Column H18 if cells I18 to cells I27=500. I started the code but couldn't go on to finish it since i am not really versed in vba

```vb
Sub SetPrintArea()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim x As Long, result As Boolean
   result = True
For x = 18 To 128
   If Worksheets("AR-MD").Range("H" & x).Value <> ActiveSheet.Cells(8, 19).Value Then
       result = False
   End If
   If Not result Then Exit For
Next x
    
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AR-MD")


ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = Union(ws.Range("g1:g17"), ws.Range("i1:i17"),ws.Range("Result").Address

End Sub


I want to be able to print the result condition but i dont know how to include it in the statement
```

Comment: Have a look on here, many q with example code exist.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Union` method:

```
ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = Union(ws.Range("g1:g17"), ws.Range("i1:i17")).Address
```

Comment: how to add a counter for the other columns so don't repeat it for j ,k and so on columns. Also how to add an if statement with ws.Range so it pick up the cells you want on a conditional basis @JMP